# Taxation of US LLC in India

Tags: united-states, india, non-resident, limited-liability-company, online-brokerage

I am a non-resident of the USA, and a resident of India for tax purposes. Suppose I set up my US brokerage account as an LLC in the USA. What taxes will I owe on this account in India? What taxes will I owe in the USA?

Answer (score 0):

You would own taxes on capital gains in India.